# Column order manipulation bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to reorder the columns in mobile view using bootstrap.

Currently on desktop columns are like as.

```
[a- long block][b][c]
[d][e][f - long block]
```

HTML for this is

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

On mobile i want the order like as below:

```
[a - long block]
[b]
[c]
[f - long block]
[d]
[e]
```

I tried using `col-sm-push-12` to `f` column but no success. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you always remember to think mobile first when working with Bootstrap. Try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">a</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">b</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">c</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">f</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-6">d</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-6">e</div>
</div>
```

And a working example: http://www.bootply.com/QILyva5K0q

Comment: Good *standard* alternative. I was thinking OP was trying to push the `col-xs-12`

Answer (score 0):

`push-*` and `pull-*` will not work on columns that have 100% width i.e. `col-*-12`.

You can use the [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) solution for the `xs` devices.

Also check for the 12 column grid system. Your current grid total for `sm` is `15(9+3+3)` which will not render what you expect for desktop columns.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row.second {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Vertical stacking */
  }
  .row.second > div:last-child {
    order: -1; /* Default is 0, so this is aligned to the top */
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">a</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">b</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">c</div>
</div>
<div class="row second">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">d</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">e</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">f</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need to resort to flexbox, Bootstrap gives you everything you need.

Comment: It will work on all major browsers except IE9. Add vendor prefixes to support IE9+.